# Build failed because of error spawn enomem in gatsby in amplify server. how to fix?

Tags: gatsby, aws-amplify, spawn

I have encountered the build error like this when deploying **Gatsby** project in **AWS Amplify** server.
Project is built successfully in local, but the build failed because of the following error in amplify server. Please let me know the solution.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF9ap.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say with 0 details. I've made a quick research and this is what I've found:

- If you have extremely large images (up to `4000px` wide for example), try to resize towards a lower number (`1920px` for example)
- If you tweaked the build command adding some environment variables (`GATSBY_CPU_COUNT` for example), try lowering the number:

  ```
  GATSBY_CPU_COUNT=1 npx gatsby build
  ```
- Check if the environment variables are defined in Amplify or in the corresponding configuration files

Related topics:

- https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/13980
- https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/16381
- https://discuss.circleci.com/t/build-fails-with-error-spawn-enomem/30537/9